# when page loaded, add text into p tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a web page now.

here is the key components of the `html`

```
<span class='codeId' id='codeId1'>456</span>
<p class='codeDescription' id='description1'></p>

<span class='codeId' id='codeId1'>789</span>
<p class='codeDescription' id='description2'></p>
```

The `codeIds` are obtained from database, so when page loaded, they will show up,
however, the `codeDescription` need to be obtained from `webservices request call` from third party, basically you send the `code` to their site and they will send response back.

I want to add responses to `codeDescription` after the page loaded automatically.

If using a button, I can do a `click` function for the `p` tag, but can this be done by itself?

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
     webserviceCall(code, callback(res){
          $('p').text(res['description']);
     });
})
```

Comment: By "done by itself" do you mean based on the page load event instead of a click event? You could wrap it with `$( document ).ready(function() {// web service call goes here } );`

Comment: @mkaatman oops, how could I forgot...

Answer (score 0):

as @mkaatman mentioned in his comment you can use document.ready...

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    webserviceCall(code, callback(res){
          $('p').text(res['description']);
     });
} );
```